# Need help for configuring VirtualHost of Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, mediawiki

I have virtual machine running Ubuntu.
I want to type in browser "http://localhost/mwiki" and see my MediaWiki site.
I put this site into /var/www/mwiki folder and I configured Apache "default" file.
But when I try to open this site in browser - following web page opened:
" The requested URL /mwiki/ was not found on this server
Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.6.2 Server at localhost Port 80".

Also on this server is running another site (ReviewBoard system). 
And it runs perfectly. When I type "localhost/reviews" I get the index page of this site.
I have minimal knowledge of configuring Apache.

Please, help.

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/www/mwiki"
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 

    <Location "/mwiki">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Location>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/www/reviews.mysite.com/htdocs"
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 

# Error handlers
ErrorDocument 500 /errordocs/500.html

# Serve django pages
<Location "/reviews/">
    PythonPath "['/var/www/reviews.mysite.com/conf'] + sys.path"
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE reviewboard.settings
    SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE "/var/www/reviews.mysite.com/tmp/egg_cache"
    SetEnv HOME "/var/www/reviews.mysite.com/data"
    SetHandler mod_python
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    PythonAutoReload Off
    PythonDebug Off
    # Used to run multiple mod_python sites in the same apache
    PythonInterpreter reviewboard_reviews_mysite_com
</Location>

<Location "/reviews/media">
    SetHandler None
</Location>

# Serve static media without running it through mod_python
# (overrides the above)
<Location "/reviews/errordocs">
    SetHandler None
</Location>

<Directory "/var/www/reviews.mysite.com/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# Alias static media requests to filesystem
Alias /reviews/media "/var/www/reviews.mysite.com/htdocs/media"
Alias /reviews/errordocs "/var/www/reviews.mysite.com/htdocs/errordocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: BTW, the manual: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a misunderstanding of how `<VirtualHost >` works. When using name-based virtual hosting (that is, same IP, multiple hostnames to distinct them), you need to have unique `ServerName`s.

Furthermore, you've set your `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/mwiki` which causes `http://localhost/` to show your wiki. Since you've one ServerName only (`localhost`), I suggest you to add an [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) instead of a virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/reviews.mysite.com/htdocs"
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    Alias /mywiki /var/www/mwiki
    # ...
```

Virtual Hosts are only useful if you've multiple IPs or hostnames. Examples:

```
# Use ServerNames to distinct virtual hosts on 127.0.0.1
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName site1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName site2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    ServerName meh.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/meh.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Added to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   site1.example.com
127.0.0.1   site2.example.com
# note: the next line is not included in the vhost config
127.0.0.1   invalid.example.com
127.0.0.2   meh.example.com
```

You can now visit the hosts using the {site1,site2,meh}.example.com domains. If you open 127.0.0.1 or `invalid.example.com`, the first vhost (`site1.example.com`) will be picked.

Comment: thanks! I was trying to solve this problem for 3 days :)

Comment: @upstream: ouch, remember that if you've no clue, read the manual at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/