# Does using apache VirtualHost disable access to non-VirtualHost directories?

Tags: mac-osx, apache-2.2, virtualhost

Very similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/274079/need-help-for-configuring-virtualhost-of-apache), I just wanted to clarify one thing. If I begin with a vanilla Mac OS X Apache install (using their default `httpd.conf` file), and then add a named VirtualHost to my apache install, how do I access the files in the original `<Directory>` directive? Do I need to re-specify the original `<Directory>` I was using to serve documents as a *second* named VirtualHost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your idea is right.

The base configuration acts as a default virtual host if you don't have a vhost matching a connection, so if you're going from 0 vhosts to 1, you might shoot right to two where the first-listed in the set of NVH'es doesn't override the DocumentRoot from the base configuration.  The 2nd NVH then has ServerName/ServerAlias for the stuff you actually wanted to be different.